# SNAP leaves behind some references after removal of NMAP package, causing APT version of NMAP not to be found

Tags: bash, snap, nmap

To test I first installed NMAP on my Ubuntu 20.04 using a snap, but that version gave a dnet error (Failed to open device enp1s0), so I removed the snap package and installed the native version with apt instead.

The apt version works fine if I include the full path, but if I run nmap without the full path I get:
-bash: /snap/bin/nmap: No such file or directory
(Note the /snap/bin/ path...)

How do I remove that reference, so that it can find the nmap installed in /usr/bin?

(I tried searching the Internet with DDG, but there are either NO hits or TOO MANY, depending on the search keywords used!)

Because user535733 (great username, BTW!) asked for it, the information [s]he asked for:

```
# snap list nmap
error: no matching snaps installed
# snap remove nmap
snap "nmap" is not installed
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1289599/edit) to show the complete output of `snap list nmap` and of `sudo snap remove nmap`. One assumes the namp snap didn't work for you after running `sudo snap connect nmap:network-control`, which the instructions are quite clear about. Please provide feedback to the snap author so they can fix the snap.

Comment: I did not add that, as there is nothing to see there...
No instructions are provided when doing "snap install nmap", so no, I did not run 'snap connect nmap:network-control", as I did not know I had to! 
If a package system requires me to go search for additional instructions to get things working, it is useless. (PERIOD! Not gonna discuss my opinion on that!)  

This question is about making sure my APT installed NMAP is working, I don't care about the snap version at this time, except that it is screwing up command finding on my system!

Comment: BTW, I resolved it by completely removing SNAPD from the host.

Comment: Opening a new terminal should fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Logix, but if it were that easy, I wouldn't have had to ask...  ;)

Comment: I had that happen with multiple snaps and that's how it was fixed for me... The terminal remembers the old binary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removed SNAPD from my host. Don't need it, don't want it, problem gone!

Comment: Even I understand your frustration, this is not a solution for your specific problem.

Comment: Talk about a useless necropost...